# Laravel not creating authenticated session for user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am doing user authentication using a custom table. I am able to login successfully as when I do in `AuthController.php`

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    dd($user);
}
```

I am getting the user details.

But when I access some other route and in the respective controller when I do

- `dd(Auth::user())` returns `null`
- `dd(session()->all())` returns `_token`
- `dd(Auth::check())` returns `false`

I am using `public_users` table for authentication and `public_email` , `public_password` fields for doing the authentication so I have changed the `App\User.php` file as follows:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'public_users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'public_users_id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'public_email',
        'public_password'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'public_password'
    ];

    // Override required, Otherwise existing Authentication system will not match credentials
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->public_password;
    }
}
```

and in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php` I have added the below code

```
public function loginUsername()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'public_email';
}

public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    dd($user);
}
```

and my `config/auth.php` has

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\User::class,
    ]
]
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I create user session?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved!

I removed  `dd($user)` from `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php` which was closing the Request LifeCycle and creating a new token each time. All I needed was to redirect which is default in `handleUserWasAuthenticated` method in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php`

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `auth()->user()` after login